# Python web crawling code with CSS seletor

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

link_list = list()

header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://www.musinsa.com/brands/poloralphlauren"
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=header)
sourcecode = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(sourcecode, "html.parser")

for href in soup.find("div", class_="article_info").find_all("list_info"):
    link_list = link_list.append(href.find("a")["href"])
    time.sleep(0.1)

print(link_list)
```

I made above code, But it shows nothing. Did I make this code wrong by using incorrect selctor, or any problem in here?

I want to crawl each link for a goods item on that site. I do not know html, css so can't catch my fault. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The tag(s) your are looking for aren't contained in the HTML source code of the site but rather are rendered dynamically with Javascript.

Try this instead to get all links for items:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.musinsa.com/brands/poloralphlauren"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content)

wrapper = soup.find("div", class_="boxed-list-wrapper")

results = []
for elem in wrapper.find_all("a", {"name":"goods_link"}):
    results.append(elem.get("href"))
results = set([x.replace("//", "https://") for x in results])

results
```

Output

```
{'https://www.musinsa.com/app/goods/2683871',
 'https://www.musinsa.com/app/goods/2683872',
 'https://www.musinsa.com/app/goods/2697577',
 'https://www.musinsa.com/app/goods/2697578',
 'https://www.musinsa.com/app/goods/2697579',
 'https://www.musinsa.com/app/goods/2697580',
 'https://www.musinsa.com/app/goods/2697581',
 'https://www.musinsa.com/app/goods/2697582',
...
```

Comment: Thank you for advice!!!! I tried to my first crawling, but it was not easy for using selectors, class with html and css or js due to my poor knowledge.  It was very helpful for me. God bless You!

Comment: @Null물을흘린다 You are welcome! I am glad that this was helpful for you. Please accept the answer so that others can see that your question is solved. All the best to you too!

Comment: It seems that I need to more reputaion for accepting your answer. PLEASE wait! I will try to do it as soon as possible.

Comment: Sure. And no worries. Take your time. Thanks and all the best for your project!